# 401.2 appearing on localhost

Tags: authentication, iis, localhost, windows-8.1

I suddenly started getting HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized page on my localhost.

I enabled SSL then disabled it and got 401.2 when running locahost.

I noticed there was anonymous authentication disabled flagg added to the project properties file so I undid the changes to project file but the 401.2 error didn't go away.

I restarted my machine in hope the IIS will default to previous settings if anything changed but it didn't. The problem persists.

I have Anonymous Authentication enabled for my default site IIS Manager.

I was swithcing on and off SSL on my localhost multiple times but never had something like this.

Any ideas what else I could check? Thanks

Comment: Without seeing your environment, it would be impossible to tell. "I noticed there was anonymous authentication disabled flagg added to the project properties file so I undid the changes to project file" seems to indicate that you have Visual Studio opening your project? Get rid of VS and then check again.

Comment: Thanks for replaying @Lex. Yes, I use Visual Studio 2017 for this project. Other solutions work fine both in VS 2015 & 2017, only this one got messed up for some reason. So I don't think reainstalling VS will make any difference. Rather the problem is in the solution itself.